# Multiple elements with inline "this.select" Javascript; only 1st one gets selected

Tags: javascript, forms, this

I've got a page that has multiple instances of a form. Each form has, among its other fields, this field:

```
<input class="span1" type="text" name="abc" id="abc" value="25" placeholder="25"
       onfocus="if (this.value==this.defaultValue) this.value=''; else this.select()"
       onblur="if (!this.value) this.value=this.defaultValue">
```

The problem is that when I click in any instance of the above field, the focus gets put to the first occurrence of the field. `this.select` isn't being restricted to that specific element. How can I ensure that the JS of each field targets that field for its operations?

I'm pretty sure this is an elementary JS newb issue, but since I'm a JS newb... ;)

Comment: Of course 30 seconds after posting I saw what I think the problem is: multiple identical `id` attributes. \*facepalm\* Checking to confirm...

Comment: Well then if you have solved the problem delete this question before it get's **down-voted**

Comment: Nope, that didn't solve it. :(

Comment: "The problem is that when I click in any instance of the above field, the focus gets put to the first occurrence of the field." However, I figured out the issue and answer. Posting shortly.

Comment: Ok, well I don't understand your problem, but it's doing exactly what your telling it to do.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After reading the [Quirksmode article](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html) on the subject, I realized that the problem was exactly what was being described there - the function was being referred instead of copied. From what I gathered, it's impossible to have inline JS work like I wanted for multiple instances on a single page.

My solution was to extract the JS from the HTML tags and make it into functions. I used some jQuery to do so (because jQuery!). :p

Here's the HTML:

```
<input
class="span1 hasDefaultValue"
type="text"
name="abc"
value="25"
placeholder="25">
```

And the JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function fieldFocus()
{
    if (this.value==this.defaultValue)
    {
        this.value='';
    }
    else
    {
        this.select();
    }
}
function fieldBlur()
{
    if (!this.value)
    {
        this.value=this.defaultValue;
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input.hasDefaultValue").click(fieldFocus);
    $("input.hasDefaultValue").blur(fieldBlur);
});
</script>
```

I'm sure that can be made more streamlined, but I wanted to post the answer ASAP. I might update with a streamlined solution later.

Comment: *...the function was being referred instead of copied."* That doesn't make any sense. If you have several elements with inline handlers, they each get their own function. The section in that article on inline handlers deals with function calls, like `onclick="doSomething()"`, where you won't get your expected `this` value. That doesn't have anything to do with your question.

Comment: ...and that article's section on "copying" the function is misleading. Functions are never copied when assigned. They're always a reference to the *same* function. I think that article was trying to explain `this` in terms of function "ownership", but that's a really poor way to explain it since functions aren't owned.

Comment: Whatever it did, it led me to the solution that worked for me. \*shrug\*